# Optional PO number in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, purchase-order

I am trying to make the purchase order optional at checkout but it is not working. I tried editing the file:

```
/vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html
```

Any change I make to this file is not reflected on the frontend. I also tried to override it with my template

```
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_OfflinePayments/view/frontend/web/template/payment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe your file path is wrong and should be `templates`, you have `template`

Comment: I tried changing to templates and that didn't work.

Comment: Can you update your full path, it cuts off after `.../payment`